# read file and write to file error in python

Tags: python, readfile, writefile

well I'm getting this error when I try to use login option
"local variable 'register' referenced before assignment"

```
def logins():
    choice = int(input("1) Do you want to Login?: \n2) Do you want to Register?: \n"))
    
     if choice == int(2):
        info = input("choose UserName: \n")
        password = input("choose PassWord: \n")
        register = open("D:\login\Login.txt", "r+")
        register.write(info + "\n" + password)

    if choice == int(1):
        infos = input("choose UserName: \n")
        passwords = input("choose PassWord: \n")
        if register == str(infos):
            print("Welcom Back! ")
            #register.close()


logins()
```

Comment: The variable `register` is only defined if the user enters 2.

Comment: hey thank you for commenting and helpping but this veriable is for open file

Comment: Not directly related, but please also consider using context manager when handling I/O streams such as files. See [here](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#using-the-python-with-statement)

Answer (score 2):

I think this code may help you.

As you use `register` variable in both case, then you can defined this variable outside the if statement.

```py
def logins():
    choice = int(input("1) Do you want to Login?: \n2) Do you want to Register?: \n"))
    
    register = open("D:\login\Login.txt", "r+")
    if choice == 2: # 2 is already int no need to change it to int.

        info = input("choose UserName: \n")
        password = input("choose PassWord: \n")
        register.write(info + "\n" + password)



    if choice == 1: # 1 is already int no need to change it to int.
        infos = input("choose UserName: \n")
        passwords = input("choose PassWord: \n")
        if register == str(infos):
            print("Welcom Back! ")
    register.close()




logins()
```

Comment: thank you guys its been solved really appreciate it

Comment: `2` is already an integer, there's no need to cast it to an integer again with `int(2)`. And `infos` is the return value from `input` so it's a string and you don't need `str(infos)`.

Comment: @Matthias This is in OP's post. Anyway, I change it.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I know and since you decided not to mention it because it's not part of the original problem I did.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for telling me, Now I edit my post. 